# Simultaneously creating instance and class methods with the same name in a ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way for me to simultaneously create a class and an instance method in a ruby class that have the same name?
I have a version of this created in the class `Foo`

```
class Foo 
   def self.bar
      "hello world" 
   end

   def bar
     self.class.bar
   end
end
```

While this works, is there a more elegant way of achieving this? Right now, I would have to duplicate ~10 methods as instance and class methods.

Comment: If you make the methods as a module you can both `extend` and `include` to get the methods in both contexts

Comment: Have a look at [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Module.html#method-i-module_function)

Answer (score 3):

you can use Ruby's `Forwardable` like this:

```rb
# in foo.rb
class Foo
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegators :Foo, :bar, :baz, :qux

  def self.bar
    "hello bar"
  end

end
```

then

```
> Foo.bar #=> "hello bar"
> Foo.new.bar #=> "hello bar"
```

You can also use `method_missing` like this:

```rb
class Foo
  DelegatedMethods = %i[bar baz qux]

  def method_missing(method)
    if DelegatedMethods.include? method
      self.class.send method
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def self.bar
    "a man walked into a bar"
  end
end
```